# AutoFill Large Number of Cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula in Excel that I would like to autofill to 999,999 other cells. How can I do this without dragging the autofill handle down the entire sheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill a large series (over 10,000 rows) in Microsoft Excel without dragging or selecting cells?](https://superuser.com/questions/1373214/how-to-fill-a-large-series-over-10-000-rows-in-microsoft-excel-without-draggin)

Comment: [Possible to apply a function to an entire column?](https://superuser.com/q/947185/241386), [Apply Formula to a Range of Cells without Drag and Drop](https://superuser.com/q/180345/241386), [How to make Excel 2010 auto-fill new row with formulas?](https://superuser.com/q/554685/241386), [Excel Auto-Fill a Series Without Mouse](https://superuser.com/q/270018/241386)

Answer (score 19):

The key is to select all the cells from the one that has the formula all the way down and then fill down the formula. These steps do that quickly:

Select the cell with the formula, then while holding down the Shift key, press the End key and then press the down arrow; now release the Shift key. This will resize the selection to include the blank cells below the active cell; if all cells below are blank, it will resize the selection all the way to the end of the sheet.

Once the range is selected, press Ctrl-D to fill down the formula.

Comment: This only repeats the value in the first cell. Unlike dragging the fill handle, which will automatically increment certain things. How to get the auto-increment?

Comment: Turns out that's answered and links back here: https://superuser.com/questions/841439/excel-auto-fill-a-column-with-increment?lq=1

Comment: The OP was asking how to fill down _formulas_, not values.

Answer (score 4):

The problem: User has a formula in a cell and wishes to copy it to the next 999,999 rows.  Simple techniques like copy'n'paste are too primitive because they don't go fast enough, and 999,999 is a large number.

Here is one solution:

1. Type 1 into a cell at the top of the worksheet, let's say Cell A1
   Result: 1 appears in Cell A1
2. Type +1+A1 into cell A2 
   Result: 2 appears in Cell A2
3. With the pointer at Cell A2, click -C to copy
4. Move the pointer to Cell A3
5. Hold down Ctrl and Shift and click , then click Down Arrow
   Result: All of Column A is highlighted, from A3 to A1048576
6. Hold down Ctrl and click V to paste
   Result: Column A now contains integers 1 to 1048576
7. Hold down Ctrl and click F to find
8. In the Find What box, enter 1000000 and press Enter
   Result: Cell A1000001 is highlighted
   Now your pointer is in Cell A1000001
9. Hold down Ctrl and Shift, then click End
   Result: Everything down to the bottom is highlighted
10. Click Delete
    Result: Only Rows 1 through 1000000 remain, showing values 1 to 1000000
11. Hold down Ctrl and click Home to return to Cell A1
12. In Cell A1, enter your formula, for example +"B"&ROW()
13. Click Ctrl and C to copy
14. Hold down Ctrl and Shift, then click End and Down
15. Hold down Ctrl and click V to paste
    Result: Column A now contains the text B1 through B1000000 but no further
16. Row 1000000 is now identified because it is the bottom-most non-blank cell
17. You may place text into other cells in Row 1000000 to identify bottoms

Answer (score 3):

Double clicking the auto-fill handle (small rectangle at bottom left of selected cells) will auto-fill the column, until it detects a blank cell to its left.

See for example:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/a-quick-fill-handle-trick-for-microsoft-excel/

Comment: Only useful, if you already have 999,999 entries already entered to the left or right.

Answer (score 2):

*My solution is inspired from Jay Jacob's answer, and I do believe that 
 following is the easiest way to do it.*

1. Put the value in Formula cell A1 and copy it.
2. Use the Name Box (left to the Formula Bar), type in the last cell you need. 
   [for example A999999 for 999999 rows in column A or C999999 for selecting 
   999999 rows across 3 columns]
3. Once the pointer is on this cell, hold Ctrl+Shift and tap
   the Left and Up keys or the Ctrl+Shift+Home bottons to select all the cells 
   from the last desired cell to the first cell needed to be filled.
4. Finally Paste it.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENRE.png)

1. type 1 in 1st cell.
2. type formula in 2nd as i want incremental series to fill till A20000 cell
3. copy formula from A2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz0uF.png)

4. Now goto cell address/range selection box and type range :A20000 next to A2 i.e A2:A20000

5. Press enter once
6. Now paste formula copied in step 3.