# Need to add newline(s) and space(s) inside a cell in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data in an Excel cell which is delimited by `,`. 
For example: `abc,bde,fgh`.
I used the formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", CHAR(10) & CHAR(13))` to change the commas to line breaks. Therefore, the data became like below:

```
abc    
bde  
fgh
```

However, my requirement is to add spaces inside the cell, so that output would look like:

```
abc  
  bde     
   fgh
```

So, the second line has 2 spaces in the front, the 3rd line has 3 spaces in the front, and the 4th line has 4 spaces in the front, sequentially. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you want 2 spaces in 2nd line and 3 spaces in 3rd one, or 1 space in 2nd line and 2 spaces in the 3rd?

Answer (score 2):

If you have only a few lines to reach, then you can achieve it with nested SUBSTITUTE:
`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",", CHAR(10)&REPT(" ",2),1),",",CHAR(10)&REPT(" ",3),1),",",CHAR(10)&REPT(" ",4),1)`

Comment: I have millions of lines :(

Comment: millions of cells to format, or millions of items in a cell?

Comment: millions of cells to format

Comment: What is the shape of your data you need to format? One column? Multiple / all columns in a range? One column in several tables?

Comment: It's one column(A) with close to 1 million rows.

Comment: There are a lot of tips on the internet how you can do that, like this: http://superuser.com/questions/180345/apply-formula-to-a-range-of-cells-without-drag-and-drop